# Recommendation for open source software to create web font from directory of SVG files

Tags: automation, svg, font

I'm currently working on an open source product that contains a Web UI that utilizes font icons.  The build process runs on ANT now, but we're in the process of moving to Maven.  To create the font icons, I currently upload individual SVG files to an online service (icomoon), map each glyph to an appropriate character, and generate the web font files.  Those are downloaded and copied into my product's source tree.

I'd like to automate the process, so I can create a directory of SVG files where the name of the SVG file is the mapped character (ex. 'x'.svg would map to the 'x' character) and all the SVG files would be added to create .ttf, .woff, and .eot files based on the name of the directory.

So something like:

```
/src
  /font
    /iconFont
      x.svg
      y.svg
      z.svg
```

would be scripted to generate:

```
/build
  /font
    iconFont.eot
    iconFont.ttf
    iconFont.woff
```

and each font file would have 3 characters (x,y,z) defined in them.  Is this a) possible and if so b) does anyone have recommended open source software to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.